# How Can I Shorten This Code

Tags: c#

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString() +
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" +
                         dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[5].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[6].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[7].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[8].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[9].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[10].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" + 
                         dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + 
                   "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[11].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + 
                   "%" ;
}
```

Maybe this Rows[11] to [250].. or more than..
Can I shorten this code.
Please help me ..
I am sorry to my bad english :(..

Comment: A simple nested `for` loop would do the trick...

Comment: ...yes, but don't forget to use `StringBuilder` :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with `StringBuilder`, works for any number of rows/columns:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            sb.Append(cell.Value).Append('&');

        // Replace the last '&' with a '%'
        if (sb.Length != 0)
            sb[sb.Length - 1] = '%';
    }

    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

`StringBuilder` will build a string without having to allocate a lot of `string` objects (which are immutable) and copying string data all over the place.

**Side note:** You should *really* rename your variables: `button4`, `dataGridView1`, `textBox1` etc are *really* ***terrible*** names. Use something meaningful instead, it'll save you from headaches later on.

Comment: I try it but i have an error>>>> [ERROR IMAGE](http://i.hizliresim.com/0qa9D9.jpg)

Comment: woows. Thats great . Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) loop:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
     {
         textBox1.Text += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "&" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "%"
     }
}
```

You could use another for loop for the other "&" values if you want. An optimization would be to use [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for create the string, and then set the textbox text.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("%",
                            from row in dataGridView1.Rows
                            select string.Format("{0}&{1}&{2}&{3}",
                                                 row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                                                 row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                                                 row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                                                 row.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: This is brilliant and more readable than I anticipated when I saw "Use LINQ" at the first place.